# Webworker from different domain loaded via blob throwing importscripts failed to load

Tags: web-worker

I have a webworker which is on CDN and is being loaded as a blob, but it's throwing this error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://assets.***.com/static/js/**.chunk.worker.js' failed to load.
    at blob:https://www.**.com/8082fe6c-b64e-498d-b9bf-f04284f****:1:1
```

However, I can see in sources and in the network tab that the file is showing up and in the chrome task manager it also says that the page is running the web worker.

This is how the worker is being loaded

```
        var _Worker = window.Worker;
    window.Worker = function (url, opts) {
        const workerPath = `importScripts(${JSON.stringify(url)})`;
        var blob = new Blob([workerPath], {
            type: 'text/javascript',
        });
        return new _Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), opts);
    };
```

Comment: Check your network panel, see what response was sent from the server. It certainly wasn't a text/javascript, and it probably has nothing to do with how you started your worker.

Comment: Response is application/javascript, I did a local setup to test it out with worker loading from port 3000 and app running o port 5000, if i use a simple worker, it works, but if i replace it with the contents of file generated by webpack build it throws this error, only difference i saw in headers was that transfer encoding was chunked, not sure if that has anything to do with it